# How to specify commit author on the fly?

Tags: git

I want to do a commit in a repo.  I don't want to set me as the default person signing, i.e. want to avoid `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` and `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`. So I am doing `git commit -m "Message" --author="My Name <my_email@email.com>"`, but Git says

```
Committer identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

How can I sign only this commit?

Comment: Signing and author information are two unrelated pieces of information. What's the problem with configuring one user (could be a dummy user) and then using a different one while committing?

Comment: You can use `--local` instead of `--global` to set the author and email for the current project, rather than for all projects.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL environment variables before your commit. See the [explanation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) about this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Your Name" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=you@example.com git commit -m "Message"
```

Comment: `export` meanse Bash and in Bash it can be a one-liner as simple as `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Your Name" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=you@example.com git commit -m "Message"`

Comment: If you assign a bash variable without export then the child process (git in our case) will not see this variable.

Comment: @alexeionin Those assignments are part of the command, not executed in the shell before the command is executed. Such pre-command assignments directly modify the environment the command to be run without modifying the *current* environment.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for explaining this. I simplified the answer as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think you can avoid editing your configuration. However, you can remove the `--global` flag and it will save the name/email for the local repository instead of overwriting your global settings.

So you could set the local configuration, sign the commit, then unset the configuration:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git commit -m "Message"
git config --unset user.email
git config --unset user.name
```

Which I admit is a bit tedious, especially if you are committing this way frequently.

You can also edit this local configuration file with `git config --edit`, where you can comment out your name/email whenever you want to "sign out".